# Write text to file in Flutter(Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to create a new file and write a string into it. Examples that I can find all seems to pertain to writing to an existing file.

```
String fileName = 'myFile.txt';
String contents = 'hello';
void writeToFile(String fileName, String contents){
    File outFile = File('content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document/document_root/' + fileName);
    outFile.writeAsString(contents);
  }
```

This results in the following error, as expected

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document/document_root/myFile.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

How can I create a new file in which I can write my contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the path exists? `writeAsString` does create the file if it doesn't exists, but it doesn't create the full folder structure up to the file you're trying to write to. Also, you might not have the rights to write in the path you've specified.

Anyway, you'd better use [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to get the folders' path instead of hard-coding them.

Comment: I have tried using path_provider, but whenever I call a path_provider method I get the error "Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getStorageDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)". When I search into the path_provider files, the methods are indeed not implemented. I'm not sure if I installed the wrong files or if I am calling it wrong

Comment: That's unexpected. For which platform are you developing? Most methods of `path_provider` have different results depending on the platform